# Add multiple instances of CCSprite to CCPhysicsNode

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Hi when I run this code I can't keep track of the position of the _monster1 instances as they are being reassigned each time the loop starts, I want to keep track of the x position of each monster that is created (on the update method) until it is destroyed by the hero character, how do I do this? Physics world is a CCPhysicsNode and Monster1 is a CCSprite. Thanks.

```
    @interface GameScene()

    @property (nonatomic) Monster1 *monster1;

    @end

    -(void)addMonster:(CCTime)dt {

    _monster1 = [[Monster1 alloc] init];
    ......
    [_physicsWorld addChild:_monster1];
    }

    -(void)update:(CCTime)delta
    {
        if (_monster1.position.x >= 300) {
           /* do things */
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to use an array (e.g. `NSMutableArray`) and add monsters into it, instead of using a single instance variable. Then in `fixedUpdate:` you need to iterate the array. Please note that it is better to use `fixedUpdate:` instead of `update:` when working with physics objects.

Comment: I did try that but it didn't work, I'll post my attempt later

Comment: @KirillMuzykov I made a new question here, it would be nice if you could have a look, thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24394073/check-instances-on-update-loop