# Keep track of sprite position in an array on update loop

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Hi I have a loop adding monsters to an NSMutableArray

```
 - (void)addMonster:(CCTime)dt {


 _monster1 = [[Monster1 alloc] init];




for(int i=0;i<=num; i++)
{

    [spriteArray insertObject:_monster1  atIndex:num];

}

[_physicsWorld addChild:_monster1];


num++;
}
```

in my update loop this code is meant to check if each sprite has passed a certain point:

```
for (int i=0; i <= num; i++) 
{
    CCSprite *tempSprite = (CCSprite *) [spriteArray objectAtIndex:i];


    if (tempSprite.position.x > 100) {

    structurelife--;


    }

}
```

However this code isn't working (to decrease the int structurelife depending on how many monsters are passed that point, I'm pretty stuck so any help would be appreciated). The position of the Sprite remains at 0,0 even though it is moving accross the screen.

Comment: This inserts _monster1 num times into the spriteArray: for (int i=0;i<=num; i++) { [spriteArray insertObject:_monster1  atIndex:num]; }  ... no idea if this is related to the issue (probably not) but likely not what you intended. Also you can replace the update loop with fast enumeration: for (CCSprite* tempSprite in spriteArray) { .. }

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I changed i=0 to num as only wanted one. If you can look at my new problem I would appreciate it, if you need any clarification let me know as I'm just a beginner. I will also look into fast enumeration. Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24395950/removing-sprites-from-array-on-physicscollision

Answer (score 0):

Based on what your OP is trying to do and based on the code you wrote, your code is not correct. You state you are trying to add "monsters" to an array but instead what you are doing is adding pointers to the same monster to the array over and over again.

Your loop is essentially adding the same monster to it multiple times, rather than adding different monsters to the array. Whether it is the only problem with your code can't be determined by the small amount that was posted, but to start your method should look like this based on what you seem to be trying to do:

```
- (void)addMonster:(CCTime)dt
{
    for (int i=0; i<=num; i++)
    {
        Monster1 monster = [[Monster1 alloc] init];
        [spriteArray insertObject:monster atIndex:num];
        [_physicsWorld addChild:monster];
    }

    num++;
}
```

But again this is based on the code you have posted.

I hope this helped.

Comment: I just wanted one monster so changed i=0 to i=num. The problem was the second loop was i<= num instead of i < num so had an out of bounds array error. I have a new problem removing sprites from an array with an out of bounds message, maybe you can help I'll post in a minute :)

Comment: In that case you can remove the loop since you are not looping anything but instead you are adding just one monster to the list.