# Removing Sprites from Array on physicscollision

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

```
    - (BOOL)ccPhysicsCollisionBegin:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair monsterCollision:    (CCNode *)monster projectileCollision:(CCNode *)projectile {

    for (CCSprite *spr in spriteArray)
    {
        if (_monster1.lives == 0) 
        {
            NSMutableArray *spritesToRemove = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];                
            // Remove the sprite from its parent here.
            [spr removeFromParent];
            // However, leave the "spr" in ssprites array - just "mark" it for deletion.
            [spritesToRemove addObject:spr];

            if ([spritesToRemove count]> 0) {

                [spriteArray removeObjectsInArray:spritesToRemove];
            }
        }
    }

[projectile removeFromParent];
return YES;
```

}

I am getting an error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'.

What I want to happen is this: when a monster is hit, if it's lives are 0 it is removed from  the physicsworld. No matter where abouts I put the removeobjects bit I get the same error. Thanks. This was fixed by moving the removeObjects bit outside the loop. This next bit is why I wanted it, to remove the monster from this array, maybe I am going about the wrong way and you can get it from the physics body monster I don't know.

```
    -(void)update:(CCTime)delta
    {

 int multiplier = 0;

for (CCSprite* tempSprite in spriteArray)
{
    CGPoint nodePosition = tempSprite.position;


    if (nodePosition.x > 470) {

    multiplier++;

    structurelife = structurelife-(1*multiplier);

    }


}
```

}

Comment: move the [spriteArray removeObjectsInArray:spritesToRemove]; after the for loop. As it stands you are trying to remove sprites at every iteration.

Comment: Your code is a bit confusing and I'd suggest rewriting it. Based on what you wrote what you should be doing is looking to see if *that* monster that was hit needs to be removed from the scene. But why are you looking at something called _monster when that is not necessarily the monster that was hit (assuming there is more than one)? Why are you looping over anything in this method? There doesn't seem to be a point to the loop. Why do you have a temp array of objects to remove, that will only ever have 1 item based on what you wrote, just to remove them the next line?

Comment: That fixed it thanks. @AllenS I want to add instances of monsters to the spriteArray and then check each individual sprite in the array to see if it has 0 lives then remove it. I made a class Monster which makes instances monster1 with an int lives.   If this monster1 is added to the array, how can I check the lives of each one? You are right it needs rewriting as all of the monsters get removed now when I kill one, I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: Why are you removing *other* monsters from an array in a collision method triggered by another monster? Your physics method looks like it passes in the monster that was hit into it? Why not just subtract a life from that monster, see if the life is 0, and if so remove that monster? Based on the code you've posted in this thread and the other, I have yet to see a need to have an array of monsters. If the only point of the array is to determine which monster has 0 lives, then you don't need it. Whenever a monster is hit you already know about him. Just test that one monster and remove if 0.

Comment: The reason for the array is to check the position of each monster all the time, if they are over a line on the x axis then it counts as you losing life. Maybe I am going about this the complete wrong way, I don't know I'm just experimenting to see what works.

Comment: For now I have just set the monster position to 0,0 before it is removed so it stays in the Array like that but then it's stuck in there forever which isn't great

Comment: @AllenS I added some code to explain why I want the Array, you are right that I need the physics body monster item removed from the Array but I have no idea how to link the monster physics body hit to the _monster1 instance variable one in the Array it is wrapped around. Thanks for your help so far.